# How to disable resizing of flash scene in flash desktop player?

Tags: flash

I am using Flash CS5 and when I exprt my file to swf I notied that after exporting and playing it in Flash player (on my desktop) I can change the size of the window and the scene itself eventthough I have set the width and height dimension to e.g. 468x60.

So, the bad thing is that if I ahve some objects that are moving from this area and in banner I do not see them in flash player I can see all which is not good.

Is there a setting in export option to disable this behavior or some actionscript, so my client will not be able see the "mess-behind-the-scenes" :)?

I can probably remove some objects using actionscript, however if I have looping background image it is necessary to be bigger than 468px In my case 3x.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

standalone flashplayer will be resizable because it's a windowed app.
however, you can apply a 468x60 [mask](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#mask) to your root DisplayObject

**upd:**

```
var maskMC:MovieClip = _root.createEmptyMovieClip("mask", _root.getNextHighestDepth());
maskMC.beginFill(0x000000, 100);
maskMC.moveTo(0, 0);
maskMC.lineTo(0, 60);
maskMC.lineTo(468, 60);
maskMC.lineTo(468, 0);
maskMC.lineTo(0, 0);
_root.setMask(maskMC);
```

Comment: How to do that in ActionScript 2?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say what AS version.

In AS2, add to first frame
Stage.scaleMode = "noscale";

In AS3
[StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Stage.html#scaleMode)

edit // And, you can set a main mask layer

Comment: :( not working I can still resize my flash player and aI see object that are out of stage. Stage.scaleMode = "noscale"; is not working the way I need.

Comment: Of course you can resize your flash player :) but if you need to hide objects from outside you have to add a mask with the size of the stage and add all layers under that mask. Sure, it depends of your needs

Answer (score 0):

Came here from a google search and needed an AS3 version of [www0z0k's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7120373/187825). In case anyone else is in the same boat, here is what I ended up doing:

```
var square:Sprite = new Sprite();
addChild(square);
square.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
square.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);
square.graphics.endFill();
square.x = 0;
square.y = 0;
this.mask = square;
```