# How to make a window in Flash non-resizable

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

The answer on Google that I found didn't work. I want my Flash program to not be able to resize/maximize, as the default size is what it SHOULD be. I am using AS3. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If the program is running in a standalone window you won't be able to disable it from being resized, however you can disable your program from rescaling by using StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE

Comment: Are you using AIR or embedding a Flash movie in HTML? We need more info here.

Comment: I got my answer from Marcus. I was using a stand alone window. :((((((

Comment: Of course, you can't disable resizing of stand alone window, but you can draw mask on your content, maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7118482/how-to-disable-resizing-of-flash-scene-in-flash-desktop-player) will come up.